# Linux ACPI Configuration

Tags: linux, shutdown, acpi

In my Fedora Core Linux (kernel 2.6.16.11), I've been trying to test the auto-shutdown mechanism associated with the CPU temperature.  It does not automatically shutdown properly.

If my current processor temperature is 50 C and I set my ACPI configuration to shutdown at 55 C by executing the following commands at the prompt:

```
echo -n "55:50:45:40:35:30" > /proc/acpi/thermal_zone/THRM/trip_points
echo -n "1" > /proc/acpi/thermal_zone/THRM/polling_frequency
echo -n "0:0" > /proc/acpi/processor/CPU1/limit
```

Then running any software which brings my temperature way past 55 C, the system doesn't automatically shut down like I need it to.

But as long as the temperature is above 55 C, if I run the following command again:

```
echo -n "55:50:45:40:35:30" > /proc/acpi/thermal_zone/THRM/trip_points
```

Then the system shuts down immediately like I want it to!  Does anyone know why the system doesn't go down on its own?

Note that I do have '/usr/sbin/acpid' running.

Answer (score 1):

After running those 3 `echo`'s, try `cat /proc/acpi/thermal_zone/THRM/trip_points` and see what it's set to. My guess is that it gets reset after you set the other two, so I suggest you run the first `echo` you wrote only after the other two and it might help.